# Regex.Replace much slower than conditional statement using String.Contains

Tags: c#, regex, string, replace

I have a list of 400 strings that all end in "_GONOGO" or "_ALLOC".  When the application starts up, I need to strip off the "_GONOGO" or "_ALLOC" from every one of these strings.

I tried this:
'string blah = Regex.Replace(string, "(_GONOGO|_ALLOC)", ""));'

but it is MUCH slower than a simple conditional statement like this:

```
if (string.Contains("_GONOGO"))
          // use Substring
else if (string.Contains("_ALLOC"))
          // use Substring w/different index
```

I'm new to regular expressions, so I'm hoping that someone has a better solution or I am doing something horribly wrong.  It's not a big deal, but it would be nice to turn this 4 line conditional into one simple regex line.

Comment: Does your regex perform any better if you put a `$` anchor on the end of the pattern?

Comment: You should use `EndsWith` instead of `Contains`. Along with being more correct, it's faster. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While it isn't RegEx, you could do

```
string blah = string.Replace("_GONOGO", "").Replace("_ALLOC", "");
```

RegEx is great for complex expressions, but the overhead can sometimes be overkill for very simple operations like this.

Comment: Thank you, this is just fine - regex wasn't a requirement I just wanted it down to one line.

Answer (score 4):

Regex replacements may work faster if you compile the regex first.  As in:

```
Regex exp = new Regex(
    @"(_GONOGO|_ALLOC)",
    RegexOptions.Compiled);

exp.Replace(string, String.Empty);
```

Comment: Note also (from MSDN) "The Regex class is immutable (read-only) and is inherently thread safe." You can create it once and assign it to a static readonly field. See http://www.acorns.com.au/blog/?p=136

Comment: And from the Atwood Archives: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000228.html

Answer (score 3):

This is expected; in general, manipulating a string by hand will be faster than using a regular expression.  Using a regex involves compiling an expression down to a regex tree, and that takes time.

If you're using this regex in multiple places, you can use the `RegexOptions.Compiled` flag to reduce the per-match overhead, as David describes in his answer.  Other regex experts might have tips for improving the expression.  You might consider sticking with the String.Replace, though; it's fast and readable.

Answer (score 1):

If they all end in one of those patterns, it would likely be faster to drop replace altogether and use:

```
string result = source.Substring(0, source.LastIndexOf('_'));
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have that much information about your problem domain, you can make things pretty simple:

```
const int AllocLength = 6;
const int GonogoLength = 7;
string s = ...;
if (s[s.Length - 1] == 'C')
    s = s.Substring(0, s.Length - AllocLength);
else
    s = s.Substring(0, s.Length - GonogoLength);
```

This is theoretically faster than [Abraham's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424561/regex-replace-much-slower-than-conditional-statement-using-string-contains/1424612#1424612), but not as flexible. If the strings have any chance of changing then this one would suffer from maintainability problems that his does not.